# Javascript and css styles not being applied

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im getting started on JavaScript and i can't find the mistake. Ok, originally `.menu` has `right: -100` and has the JavaScript `.change` is supposed to set it to `right: 0`. But nothing happens when i click the burger button. Lines are the only that change, but menu doesn't. If anyone could help i would be kinda grateful.

```js
const menuIcon = document.querySelector (".hamburguer-menu");
const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");

menuIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navbar.classList.toggle("change");
});
```

```css
*{
  margin:0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

button{
  width:30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor:pointer;
  background: none;
  border:none;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
}

.hamburguer-menu{
  width:22px;
  position: fixed;
  /* right:0; */
  top:6%;
  padding: 0px 15px 1px 9px;
  z-index: 100;
}
  .hamburguer-menu .line1, .line2, .line3{
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    background-color:#fff;
    transition: all .3s;
  }
  .hamburguer-menu .line2, .line3{
    margin-top:4px;
  }
  .change .menu{
      position: fixed;
      right: 0;
    }

  .change .line1{
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 5px);
  }
  .change .line2{
    opacity:0;
  }
  .change .line3{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -5px);
  }
header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #34495e;
}

header nav{
  display: inline;
}

header div p{
  line-height: 100px;
  float:left;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #333;
  top:0;
  right: -100%;
  padding: 80px 0px;
}

.menu button{
  display: block;
  padding: 45px 0px;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}

.menu button:focus{
outline:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7e10ce8f03.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Digna Sulbaran</title>
</head>
<body>

<header>
  <div>
    <p>Pamela Sulbaran</p>
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="hamburguer-menu">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
      <button><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></button>
      <button><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></button>
      <button><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></button>
      <button><i class="fab fa-telegram-plane"></i></button>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>

<section class="first">
    <img src="images/grey.png" alt="">
    <h2>about me</h2>
    <h1>Pamela Sulbaran</h1>
    <div>
      <p>My name is Digna Sulbaran Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <p>contact me</p>
    </div>

</section>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The CSS selector `.change .menu` to which you apply `right: 0` would mean that `.menu` is inside `.change` (navbar), in your HTML. That is not the case in your HTML, so these CSS rules are not applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need 2 `<nav>` elements. I have connected them into one, according to your CSS and JavaScript, and now it works. Unlike JavaScript, don't forget to use `px` with the digits that are definitely pixels, like `right: 10px;` (you can ignore `px` only for **0**).

```js
const menuIcon = document.querySelector (".hamburguer-menu");
const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");

menuIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navbar.classList.toggle("change");
});
```

```css
*{
  margin:0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

button{
  width:30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor:pointer;
  background: none;
  border:none;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
}

.hamburguer-menu{
  width:22px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top:6%;
  padding: 0px 15px 1px 9px;
  z-index: 100;
}
  .hamburguer-menu .line1, .line2, .line3{
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    background-color:#fff;
    transition: all .3s;
  }
  .hamburguer-menu .line2, .line3{
    margin-top:4px;
  }
  .change .menu{
      position: fixed;
      right: 0px;
    }

  .change .line1{
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 5px);
  }
  .change .line2{
    opacity:0;
  }
  .change .line3{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -5px);
  }
header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #34495e;
}

header nav{
  display: inline;
}

header div p{
  line-height: 100px;
  float:left;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #333;
  top: 0px;
  right: -100%;
  padding: 80px 0px;
}

.menu button{
  display: block;
  padding: 45px 0px;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}

.menu button:focus{
outline:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7e10ce8f03.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Digna Sulbaran</title>
</head>
<body>

<header>
  <div>
    <p>Pamela Sulbaran</p>
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="hamburguer-menu">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>

    <ul class="menu">
      <button><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></button>
      <button><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></button>
      <button><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></button>
      <button><i class="fab fa-telegram-plane"></i></button>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>

<section class="first">
    <img src="images/grey.png" alt="">
    <h2>about me</h2>
    <h1>Pamela Sulbaran</h1>
    <div>
      <p>My name is Digna Sulbaran Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <p>contact me</p>
    </div>

</section>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A space is a *descendant* combinator.

`.change .menu` matches any element that is a member of the class *menu* and is a descendant of an element that is a member of *change*.

[image: screenshot of DOM]

The only element that is a member of *menu* is **not a descendant** of the element to which you add *change*.

You need to either:

- Set `change` on a *different* element which is an ancestor of the menu *or*
- Change your selector to match the actual relationship between the elements (the [next-sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) will probably be useful for that) *or*
- Restructure your HTML so you only have one `<nav>` element (this is likely the best approach).